# Error: Class &quot;Illuminate\Http\Requests\Visit\RegularExpressionRule&quot; not found in file

Tags: php, class, object, exception

So, i've had included the above mentioned class in my file but still i'm receiving this error and not being able to create the object of this class.
detailed error: Error: Class "Illuminate\Http\Requests\Visit\RegularExpressionRule" not found in file C:\xampp\htdocs\redprixx\app\Http\Requests\Visit\VisitRequest.php on line 45

snippet of the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Visit;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Http\Requests\Visit\RegularExpressionRule;

class VisitRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            response()->json([
                // 'data' => (object) [],
                'status' => false,
                'status_code' => (string) config('constants.validation_codes.unprocessable_entity'),
                'message' => $validator->errors()->all()[0]
            ], config('constants.validation_codes.unprocessable_entity'))
        );
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $id = (isset($this->visit->id) && (int) $this->visit->id != 0) ? $this->visit->id : 0;
        if ($id == 0) {
            return [
                'name_of_visited_outlet' => 'required|max:255',
                'contact_person_name' => ['required', new RegularExpressionRule('name'), 'max:255'],
                'contact_person_phone' => ['required', new RegularExpressionRule('phone'), 'max:15'],
                'email' => 'nullable|email|max:255',
                'address' => 'required|max:500',
                'area' => 'required|max:255',
                'remarks' => 'required',
                'visit_photo' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                'contact_person_name' => ['nullable', new RegularExpressionRule('name'), 'max:255'],
                'contact_person_phone' => ['nullable', new RegularExpressionRule('phone'), 'max:15'],
                'email' => 'nullable|email|max:255',
                'address' => 'nullable|max:500',
                'area' => 'nullable|max:255',
                'remarks' => 'nullable',
                'visit_photo' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
            ];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How did you install that code? Are you using Composer?

Comment: yes, i'm using composer